# What's the difference between % and ILIKE in PostgresSQL WHERE query?

Tags: postgresql

Question says it all really... I've been able to use both of these but can't tell what the difference is. Using pg_trgm module...

```
SELECT * from tbl WHERE postcode % 'w4%' LIMIT 10;


SELECT * from tbl WHERE postcode ILIKE 'w4%' LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Are you sure? I get an error on the % operator for text: [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: text % text

Comment: @FrankHeikens: the `%` operator is provided by the pg_trgm module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ILIKE` and the `%` operator are quite different.

`%` is the similarity operator used by [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). Its outputs depends on the set similarity threshold.

```sql
set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = .6;
select 'abcdef' % 'abZZef';
--> false

set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = .1;
select 'abcdef' % 'abZZef';

--> true
```

On the other hand `Ilike` looks for (partial) string equality

```sql
select 'abcdef' ilike 'abc%';
--> true
select 'abcdef' ilike 'abZ%';
--> false
```

Comment: So the `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` doesn't affect the `like` and `ilike` apart for the performace (in case you create a proper index using GIN pg_trgm and its operators). Is it correct?

Comment: @DanieleTeti Yes, they are unrelated.